# Plot Legends and curve labels inside Show

Tags: plotting, legending

Here is a simple version of my actual problem where I want to label curves inside `Show` and indicate the labelling by a legend.

```
 p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
p2 = Plot[Exp[-x] Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
Show[p2, p1, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "functions"}]
```

I have edited the resulting plot in powerpoint to show what I want it to look like. How can one make such changes inside `Show`?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Using a single `Plot`

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Exp[-x] Sin[2 x]},
 {x, 0, 2 π},
 PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "functions"},
 Epilog -> {
   Text[Style[Subscript[A, "\[TensorProduct]"], 14], {1.6, 0.9}],
   Text[Style[Subscript[A, "⊕"], 14], {0.9, 0.2}],
   Text[
    Framed[
     StringForm["`` = Tensor Prod\n`` = Tensor Sum",
      Style["\[TensorProduct]", ColorData[97][1]],
      Style["⊕", ColorData[97][2]]],
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thin]],
    {5, .7}]}]
```

[image]

Using `Show`

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}];
p2 = Plot[Exp[-x] Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 π},
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2]];
Show[p2, p1,
 Graphics[{
   Text[Style[Subscript[A, "\[TensorProduct]"], 14], {1.6, 0.9}],
   Text[Style[Subscript[A, "⊕"], 14], {0.9, 0.2}],
   Text[
    Framed[
     StringForm["`` = Tensor Prod\n`` = Tensor Sum",
      Style["\[TensorProduct]", ColorData[97][1]],
      Style["⊕", ColorData[97][2]]],
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thin]],
    {5, .7}]}],
 PlotRange -> All,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "functions"}]
```

[image]